# What exactly does Unreal Engine 4's Class Wizard do?

Tags: unreal

I know "it adds classes to your project" and "creates boiler plate code for you" but what does that actually mean? Does it do anything besides properly generate your `.h` and `.cpp` files for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used UE4 but I've used UE3.

And yes by reading at [the documentation](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Programming/Development/ManagingGameCode/CppClassWizard/index.html), I believe it indeed does *more* than setting up two files with boilerplate code. Quotation:

> This converts a content-only project into a code project.

That should mean:

- Creating a Visual Studio or Xcode solution for the generation of user DLLs,
- Preparing it for compilation (c.f. [this page](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Programming/Development/CompilingProjects/index.html)),
- Maybe some messing up with the Unreal game project and its [packaging](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Engine/Basics/Projects/Packaging/index.html), as the game will now run those custom DLLs instead (on top?) of the stock ones.

Probably more, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

It adds 'boiler plate' code to your project, based on what have you choosen. By doing this you are converting your content-only project to code project and that means that you can build it from Visual Studio/Xcode, and it will also slow down the building process. You can use the classes you have written in C++ in Blueprints, too.